# Add cases from another enum using Swift macro

Tags: swift, swift-macro

I want to create a macro which copies cases from one enum to another. I would imagine something like this:

```
enum ChildEnum {
    case childA
    case childB
}


@CaseProxy(ChildEnum.self)
enum ParentEnum {
    case parent
}
```

which will generate:

```
enum ParentEnum {
    case parent

    ///Generated
    case childA
    case childB
}
```

I tried to create the macro, but I don't know how to use `node: AttributeSyntax` to get to the members of the given type that I pass as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this design, you cannot. Macros are not full-fledged source generators. They operate on the AST, not the semantics of the code. As far as the macro is concerned, `ChildEnum.self` is just the word `ChildEnum`, a period, and the word `self`. It cannot know what cases `ChildEnum` has, unless you pass all the cases' names into the macro.

And if you do pass all the cases into `@CaseProxy`, that kind of defeats the purpose of having a macro. You might as well just write them inside the enum declaration normally.

An alternative design would be to have an additional *declaration* macro take in a `() -> Void` closure. Inside the closure, you can declare enums:

```
#ProxyableEnums {

    enum ChildEnum {
        case childA
        case childB
    }
    
    @CaseProxy(ChildEnum.self)
    enum ParentEnum {
        case parent
    }

}
```

Now both enums are "inputs" to `#ProxyableEnums`, and so `#ProxyableEnums` can read the contents of the closure, and see what cases each enum has. Then, it can find enums that are annotated with `@CaseProxy`. Using this information, `#ProxyableEnums` will expand to one or more enum declarations - for every enum without `@CaseProxy`, it will expand to that same enum declaration, and for every enum with `@CaseProxy`, it will expand to an enum declaration with the added cases. Notably, `@CaseProxy` doesn't expand to anything - it's just a "marker" for `#ProxyableEnums`.

The obvious limitation here is that the child and parent enums must be in the same file.

Here is a very simple implementation:

```
enum CaseProxy: MemberMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax, 
        providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax, 
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        []
    }
}

enum ProxyableEnums: DeclarationMacro {
    static func getEnumDeclarations(_ closureBody: CodeBlockItemListSyntax) -> [EnumDeclSyntax] {
        closureBody.compactMap { $0.item.as(EnumDeclSyntax.self) }
    }
    
    static func expansion(
        of node: some FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        let enumDecls = getEnumDeclarations(
            node.trailingClosure!.statements
        )
        
        var map = [String: EnumDeclSyntax]()
        for decl in enumDecls {
            map[decl.name.text] = decl
        }
        for decl in enumDecls {
            if let caseProxy = decl.attributes.findAttribute("CaseProxy"), 
                case let .argumentList(args) = caseProxy.arguments,
                let type = args.first?.expression.as(MemberAccessExprSyntax.self)?
                    .base?.as(DeclReferenceExprSyntax.self)?.baseName.text,
               let proxiedCases = map[type]?.memberBlock.members
                    .compactMap({ $0.decl.as(EnumCaseDeclSyntax.self) }) {
                map[decl.name.text]?.memberBlock.members
                    .append(contentsOf: proxiedCases.map { MemberBlockItemSyntax(decl: $0) })
            }
        }
        
        return map.values.map(DeclSyntax.init)
    }
}

extension AttributeListSyntax {
    func findAttribute(_ name: String) -> AttributeSyntax? {
        for elem in self {
            if case let .attribute(attr) = elem, 
                attr.attributeName.as(IdentifierTypeSyntax.self)?.name.text == name {
                return attr
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

// ...

@freestanding(declaration, names: arbitrary)
public macro ProxyableEnums(_ f: () -> Void) = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "ProxyableEnums")

@attached(member)
public macro CaseProxy<T>(_ type: T.Type) = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "CaseProxy")
```